# How state works in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, state

If in my web page I have two components and each are having there own different state so now if i change the state of one component will it effect on second component also ?

Comment: States are always local to the component. You can read about how components state works here https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, each component only are reactive with his own state